# How to find list of available shells by command-line?

Tags: shell, command-line

How to list available shells for use by command-line?

Comment: `(IFS=: && grep -rl tcsetpgrp $PATH | xargs grep -rl setrlimit)` on a Debian system seems to give a good approximation.

Comment: On Fedora 20 it returns 
`/bin/bash
/bin/crash
/bin/gdb`
(and the symlinks from `/usr/bin`).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

To list available valid login shells for use at time, type following command:

```
cat /etc/shells
```

Example:

```
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ cat /etc/shells
# /etc/shells: valid login shells
/bin/sh
/bin/dash
/bin/bash
/bin/rbash
/bin/ksh93
```

For information about shell visit [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29).

Comment: Note that this will not work for all systems. E.g. Solaris and HP-UX do not have an /etc/shells file by default.

Comment: Why do I have `/bin/true` and `/bin/false` in this list?

Comment: @bernhard - There is a good explanation of /bin/true and /bin/false here [link](http://serverfault.com/questions/519215/what-is-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false)

Answer (score 9):

You can also use
`chsh -l`
This will print the list of shells.

Example :-

```
[anurag@focused ~]$ chsh -l
/bin/sh
/bin/bash
/sbin/nologin
/usr/bin/sh
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Comment: For me, `chsh: invalid option -- 'l'`

Comment: @Pandya can you provide the complete command you are using.
You might be using it with combination of other shell methods or constructs like ((...)) or [...] or [[...]]

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rGipgDg4

Comment: Probably I've http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1@@shadow-utils.html

Comment: @Pandya 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html

This provides -l option.
Just click on the link on the top of the page, to go to linux-util man page

Comment: @Pandya
You can run your the command here and verify.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php

Comment: `shadow-utils 4.1.5.1` provides `chsh` in my case that's why I am getting [that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140286/how-to-find-list-of-available-shells-by-command-line/288394?noredirect=1#comment504359_288394) error. +1 for correct answer

Comment: @Pandya Thnx :)

Comment: `chsh: invalid option -- 'l'`, `which chsh` gives
`/usr/bin/chsh`, `dpkg -S /usr/bin/chsh` gives `passwd: /usr/bin/chsh`, `dpkg-query -l passwd` gives: passwd  version 1:4.1.5.1-1.

Answer (score 2):

On at least OpenBSD and NetBSD:

```
$ getent shells
```

On (Ubuntu) Linux and many other Unices (including BSDs):

```
$ grep '^[^#]' /etc/shells
```

On Solaris, the file `/etc/shells` may not exist.  The list of valid shells is contained in the `shells(4)` manual.  On my vanilla Solaris 11.3 system, this lists the following shells:

```
/bin/bash         /usr/bin/bash     /bin/pfbash   /usr/bin/pfbash
/bin/csh          /usr/bin/csh      /bin/pfcsh    /usr/bin/pfcsh
/bin/jsh          /usr/bin/jsh      /sbin/jsh     /usr/sbin/jsh
/bin/ksh          /usr/bin/ksh      /bin/pfksh    /usr/bin/pfksh
/bin/ksh93        /usr/bin/ksh93    /bin/pfksh93  /usr/bin/pfksh93
/bin/sh           /usr/bin/sh       /bin/pfsh     /usr/bin/pfsh
/bin/tcsh         /usr/bin/tcsh     /bin/pftcsh   /usr/bin/pftcsh
/sbin/sh          /usr/xpg4/bin/sh  /sbin/pfsh    /usr/xp4/bin/pfsh
/bin/zsh          /usr/bin/zsh      /bin/pfzsh    /usr/bin/pfzsh
/usr/sfw/bin/zsh
```

It's worth noting that on my installation, neither `/usr/sfw/bin/zsh` nor `/usr/xp4/bin/pfsh` exists...

A shorter list of valid Solaris shells (duplicates of each shell removed):

```
/bin/bash       /bin/ksh        /bin/pfcsh      /bin/pfsh       /bin/sh
/bin/csh        /bin/ksh93      /bin/pfksh      /bin/pftcsh     /bin/tcsh
/bin/jsh        /bin/pfbash     /bin/pfksh93    /bin/pfzsh      /bin/zsh
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dig into `/etc/passwd`, you could do:

```
cut -d ':' -f 7 /etc/passwd | sort -u
```

H/T @schrodigerscatcuriosity in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/631346/40454