# Why can't I get a unique list of shells?

Tags: shell, passwd, uniq

Trying to get a unique list of shells on my system. When I run this command:

```
cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 7 | uniq
```

I get:

```
/bin/bash  
/bin/sync  
/sbin/shutdown  
/sbin/halt  
/bin/bash
```

I can't figure out why `uniq` isn't doing what I want. What don't I understand?

I tried taking this output, making a copy, replacing one of the `/bin/bash` lines with the other in the copy, and then `diff`ing the files and I got no output, so I'm guessing not a hidden character?

Comment: The fact that the search "How to get a list of shells" doesn't have an associated question makes me think I could reframe this question "How to get a unique list of shells?" and it wouldn't be a duplicate. What do you think, @ilkkachu?

Comment: The thing about duplicates is not so much in the Question phrasing but the Answering of the core question. The nice thing about duplicates *is* that they are the many faces of a core issue, all of which are addressed in the linked Q&A. It seems to me that the core issue you faced here is the same "uniq doesn't appear to remove duplicates".

Comment: I found the other question, "How to get a list of shells": https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/140286/40454. So there was no reason to fret.

Comment: `getent passwd | awk -F: '{s[$7]++}END{for(i in s)print i, s[i]}'` will show the list of shells and how many users are using each. Notice that the user database is NOT always `/etc/passwd`, so you better use a nss-aware tool like `getent`.

Comment: @BrianPeterson `/etc/shells` only lists the shells that a regular user can choose with the `chsh` tool. The root can set the shell of a user to any program she likes (with `chsh` or other tool). Notice how that list does not include `/bin/sync`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because how `uniq` works, from the man:

> Note:  'uniq'  does  not  detect  repeated  lines **unless they are
> adjacent**.  You may want to sort the input first, or use 'sort -u'
> without 'uniq'.

So, better use, no need of `cat`:

```
$ cut -d ':' -f 7 /etc/passwd | sort -u
/bin/bash
/bin/false
/bin/sync
/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Or, one command

```
 awk -F: '{ print $7 | "sort -u" }' /etc/passwd
```

---

[@kojiro's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/5377/kojiro) suggestion:

```
awk -F: '!s[$7]++{print $7}' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to pass a sorted output to `uniq` to make it work.

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 7 | sort | uniq
/bin/bash
/bin/sync
/sbin/halt
/sbin/shutdown
```

Comment: And if you put the -c option on uniq, it will show you how many people are using each one.